Spin operator in arbitrary direction
How to justify that a spin operator in an arbitrary direction is given by
$$S=\sum_i \sigma_in_i$$
Where $\sigma_i$ are Pauli matrices and $n_i$ is a component of an arbitrary unit vector in $i'th$ direction.
I deliberately did not write the above expression as $S=\vec\sigma\cdot\vec n$ because i am not sure how one can treat spin operator as a vector in this case. I feel like this sought of notation would make sense if one studies operator transformations but i am not aquanted with those yet.

It is just notation/convention: Both equations you write are the same by definition.

@TobiasFünke Sure but i am not asking about convention or notation. My question is how to justify that spin in arbitrary direction is $\vec\sigma\cdot\vec n$ when pauli matrices are not vectors but operators

Yes, as I said: It is notation. It is equal to your first equation. Or is your question why the first equation is true?

@TobiasFünke Yes, that is my question, the second para of my post is just a clarification. No, it does not answer my question, mainly for the same reasons that OP of that post mentioned in the comments

See also the links therein. Your question is an exact duplicate, whether or not you are satisfied with that answer. You could try to edit your question, spelling out why exactly you feel none (!) of the other posts are satisfactory. But before that, you can also ask for clarification in the comments under an answer, for example. Note that, as you can see, this has been asked before a lot of times already here, so please use the search function.

See also this.
